# why don't my wildcards work?

Tags: command-line

In the command line, the wildcards do not seem to work.  Am I just old-school and they are not used.  The manuals seem to describe them.  A search command for *.pl should find all perl scripts...

And  *.pm should find all perl objects.  thanks  john

Comment: You've not posted the command in question, which makes it a bit hard to understand the question. `locate *.pl` and `locate *.pm` seem to find all the scripts and objects, and I hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the directory of the scripts you need to use `ls *.pm`, if you want to search the subdirectories as well you are better of with the `find` command, you would then use

```
find . -name '*.pm'
```

The first argument is the parent directory to use: the dot means from the current directory and down, if you use `/` this means that the whole filesystem will be searched, depending on your files this might take a while.

I don't recommend using the `locate` command because it gets the information from a database that might not be up-to-date. So if you add a file it won't show up in your output unless you force the database to update by

```
sudo updatedb
```

See also the man pages for more info about these commands (eg. by doing `man find`)